# Binding Canvas to UI using Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, knockout.js

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
function ViewModel(){
       self = this;
    self.myCanvas = ko.observable();
};
var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #000000;" data-bind="___:myCanvas"></canvas>

Report
<div data-bind="___:myCanvas"></div>
```

I am using the knockout.js to bind ViewModel properties to the DOM. Now, part of my GUI is rendered on a canvas element. I used JavaScript to draw the elements on the canvas. I am not able to use knockout to bind to them.

Comment: If you don't already know, it is always a recommended practice on SO to provide some piece of code that you already have, so that people can look at it and guide you appropriately...

Answer (score 2):

You could create a *[custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html)* to help store a reference to an element when the data-binds are applied.

Custom bindings have an `init` and `update` method, both of which receive the  bound `HTMLElement` as a first argument.

Here's an example that:

- Defines a custom binding that stores the element in the viewmodel's observable
- Subscribes to the element's observable to execute drawing logic

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.storeElement = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    valueAccessor()(element);
  }
}


function ViewModel() {
  self = this;
  self.myCanvas = ko.observable();

  self.myCanvas.subscribe(function initCanvas(element) {
    var ctx = element.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);

  });

};

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #000000;" data-bind="storeElement: myCanvas"></canvas>

Report
```